# Using two leds with one push button

Tags: led, c, arduino-leonardo, programming-sequence

How can I make the code of this project where I will press one time a button,  to turn on the first led (and turn off second led) and when other one press to turn on second led (and turn off the first led).

Comment: Your question is barely answerable and shows no effort of trying it yourself. You could try starting out with Arduino Tutorials instead of a project directly.

Comment: This is a poor quality lazy question. You need to exert some effort.

Comment: From the question it appears that person's first language is not english, it looks like it was possible processed through some translator.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by keeping the 'state' saved in a variable.
Depending on it's [state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine), the button will have a different effect.

After this effect, the state is updated, so that next iteration it will behave according to the other state.

```
state = led1
if(buttonpressed){
   if(state == led2){
     led1On();
     led2Off();
     state = led1;
   }else{
     led1Off();
     led2On();
     state = led2;
   }
}
```

Comment: Also check the Arduino example about debouncing buttons.

Comment: You do the OP a disservice by giving them functioning code. This allows "copy/paste programming" without learning.

Comment: This code isn't completely functional and only to illustrate how using state works. I somewhat agree that I could have used a different example as the case for which this person was asking.